# Listening to all notifications in device (iOS) to make wearable vibrate

Tags: ios, push-notification, bluetooth, apple-push-notifications

So, I'm developing a wearable device with BLE 5.0, and I want to make it vibrate everytime a notification gets on my phone, I know I can achieve this with Android.

But is it something that I can do with iOS? If not, is there any work around you would suggest?

I'm talking about notifications from any other application, not mine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the ANCS service

Comment: @Paulw11 does it matter that the apps are not owned by me? Like... can I make my BLE device do something with an Apple Plush Facebook Notifcation aimed to the Facebook Native App? Or any other application I don't own.

Comment: It seems it does work with ANCS how I want it :-) I'll appreciate if you could confirm my statement.

Comment: You can't do anything with the notifications (well, some notifications allow you to send a positive or a negative response such as answering or rejecting a call) but ANCS will deliver all notifications